# Basic Auth in Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, postman

Начал разбираться с spring security и возникла такая проблема. Что в браузере get и delete запросы можно выполнить авторизовавшись, а метод save нельзя (так как нужно тело). Для save использую postman, но даже заполнив basic auth данными, все равно получаю страницу авторизации.

Может не правильно настроил security config файл ?

Вот контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
@Slf4j
public class ProductController {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ProductController(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        log.info("Receiving all products");
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getProduct/{id}")
    public Product getProductById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.info("Receiving product by id");
        return productRepository.getReferenceById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public Product saveProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        log.info("Save products");
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Product product = productRepository.getReferenceById(id);
        log.info("delete product by id");
        if (product != null) {
            productRepository.delete(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password("user1Pass")
                .roles(UserRole.USER.name())
                .build();
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin1Pass")
                .roles(UserRole.USER.name())
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/product/save").hasRole(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
                        .requestMatchers("/product/remove/**").hasRole(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
                        .requestMatchers("/product/products").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/product/getProduct/{id}").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/product").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Вот авторизация и basic auth в postman:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код лучше текстом приводить - так можно что-то выделить и скопировать. С картинки этого не сделать. По сути вопрос - скорее всего вам не Basic авторизация нужна, но нужно повторить в Postman запрос на логин, вытащить из ответа куки и их прикреплять потом к запросам, требующим авторизации

Comment: @ЮрийСПб за картинки кода, взял на заметку - исправил.
То есть через вкладку autorization сделать авторизацию не получится как на скрине? 
Что бы автоматически заполнялись поля "please sing in"

Comment: Можно через Basic но для этого надо в спринге прописать-настроить такую возможность. Вроде бы [как-то так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739359/combining-basic-authentication-and-form-login-for-the-same-rest-api). Или можно с имеющейся авторизацией в Postman посылать запрос на авторизацию так же как это в браузере происходит, силами Postman вытаскивать заголовок с куками и его силами постмана крепить ко всем запросам другим.

Answer (score 0):

Кому будет интересно как я решил эту проблему :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){

        UserDetails ramesh = User.builder()
                .username("ramesh")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles(UserRole.USER.name())
                .build();

        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .roles(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(ramesh, admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/product/save").hasRole(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
                    .requestMatchers("/product/remove/**").hasRole(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
                    .requestMatchers("/product/products").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/product/getProduct/{id}").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/product").permitAll();
                }).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Изменив код авторизация начала работать как через браузер так и через postman.